# No automatically generated numbers with references

Tags: bibliographies

I just start learning how to use LaTeX.

I am using the Texmaker4.0.1 and MiKTeX2.9 on Win7.

All is fine, until I get to the reference part. I tried to get a sequence number in front of each reference item, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{colacl}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\sloppy

\title{Report}
\author{Z.Pyyyy}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Hello, world.
\end{abstract}

\section{Chapter 1}
Text, Text\cite{Pan}.

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
  \bibitem{Boney96} Boney, L., Tewfik, A.H., and Hamdy, K.N., ``Digital Watermarks for Audio Signals," \emph{Proceedings of the Third IEEE International Conference on Multimedia}, pp. 473-480, June 1996.
  \bibitem{MG} Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., Samarin, \emph{A LaTeX Companion}, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1994.
  \bibitem{HK} Kopka, H., Daly P.W., \emph{A Guide to LaTeX}, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1999.
  \bibitem{Pan} Pan, D., ``A Tutorial on MPEG/Audio Compression," \emph{IEEE Multimedia}, Vol.2, pp.60-74, Summer 1998.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

And I got result like this:

```
Report
Z.Pyyyy

Abstract
Hello, world.

Chapter 1
Text, Text[4].

Reference
Boney, L., Tewfik, A.H., and Hamdy, K.N., "Digital Watermarks for Audio Signals", Proceedings of the Third IEEE International Conference on Multimedia}, pp. 473-480, June 1996.
Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., Samarin, A LaTeX Companion, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1994.
Kopka, H., Daly P.W., A Guide to LaTeX, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1999.
Pan, D., ``A Tutorial on MPEG/Audio Compression," IEEE Multimedia, Vol.2, pp.60-74, Summer 1998.
```

What I want it to be is like:

```
...
Reference
[1] Boney, L., Tewfik, A.H., and Hamdy, K.N., "Digital Watermarks for Audio Signals", Proceedings of the Third IEEE International Conference on Multimedia}, pp. 473-480, June 1996.
[2] Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., Samarin, A LaTeX Companion, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1994.
[3] Kopka, H., Daly P.W., A Guide to LaTeX, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1999.
[4] Pan, D., ``A Tutorial on MPEG/Audio Compression," IEEE Multimedia, Vol.2, pp.60-74, Summer 1998.
```

Could anyone help me out ?

PS : Another quick question, what is the difference between references and citations ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: What *do* you get in front of each item in the bibliography? Rather than saying "it doesn't work", explain what you tried and what the error messages or output are.

Comment: @Werner What I want to do is to generate a reference like `[1] Boney, L. Tewfik, A.H. ...` But actually, mine result is only `Boney, L. Tewfik, A.H. ...` I just want that [1] number in front of each reference.

Comment: Does add `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` in your preamble help?

Comment: @Guido Yes, but it only solves part of my problem. I can manage to have a cite number when I add `... text\cite{Pan} ...`, and I will get a `... text[4] ...`, but still no sequence number in front of the references.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. The issue I think depends  on the class or styles you use. Probably they define an author/year citation style overriding the standard bibliography mechamisms.

Comment: What is this `colacl` package you are using.  It is likely the culprit.  This means if it is required by some journal or publisher, they may not want numbers in front of the references.  (Or perhaps it is a poorly written package.)

Comment: What and where is the package `colacl` to be found?

Comment: Regarding citations and references: you 'cite' a 'reference' in the sense that a citation provides the publication information of a reference or is a pointer to where that information can be found in your bibliography.

Comment: @jon, yeah...seems you are quite right about that package, it is from the teacher's template... I can't believe I have wasted so much time on it... may be there should be no numbers at the first place... thank you so much for helping me out !

Comment: @Werner, the website is https://code.google.com/p/crfhm/source/browse/trunk/paper/report/latex/colacl.sty?r=176 and it seems that maybe there should be no number... but still, thank you so much for the help !

Comment: @jon, thanks for the explanation of citation and reference ! It helps a lot for a newbie like me.

Comment: My pleasure.  You are right about the `.sty` file: look at line 194 and following in the link you gave.  It says that there is not supposed to be a label in the bibliography.

Comment: The `colacl` style *wants* that the bibliography is prepared with BibTeX using the `acl.bst` style. It uses an author-year citation system.

Comment: @egreg, yeah, no wonder I am confused about the meaning of like `\newcite{Spa72}` in the original template ... thanks a lot

Comment: @Z.pyyyy That's really an unfortunate name: `\textcite` (like it's in `biblatex`) would be better, perhaps along with `\parencite` instead of `\cite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`colacl`](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/~lcarlson/02-03/ctl292/colacl.sty) package you load in your code prevents any reference numbering within `thebibliography` because of the way it redefines `\@biblabel`. The following overrides that redefinition by `colacl.sty`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{colacl}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citename##1{##1}[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother

\sloppy
\title{Report}
\author{Z.Pyyyy}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Hello, world.
\end{abstract}

\section{Chapter 1}
Text, Text\cite{Pan}.

\begin{thebibliography}{100}
  \bibitem{Boney96} Boney, L., Tewfik, A.H., and Hamdy, K.N., ``Digital Watermarks for Audio Signals," \emph{Proceedings of the Third IEEE International Conference on Multimedia}, pp. 473-480, June 1996.
  \bibitem{MG} Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., Samarin, \emph{A LaTeX Companion}, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1994.
  \bibitem{HK} Kopka, H., Daly P.W., \emph{A Guide to LaTeX}, Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, 1999.
  \bibitem{Pan} Pan, D., ``A Tutorial on MPEG/Audio Compression," \emph{IEEE Multimedia}, Vol.2, pp.60-74, Summer 1998.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your code, and I got this...

(I had to comment `\usepackage{colacl}` because it didn't recognize it)

Isn't it want your want ?

[image: your code]

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I am required to use that sty. To make your latex recognize it, you can download the sty file from the Internet, and put it under the same directory as your tex file.